# Are Windows activation tools illegal?

Tags: copyright, licensing

There are several of such tools that activate Windows without buying a license. Such tools works by emulating a KMS (key management service) server that is used to activate Windows in enterprise envroinments. Are these tools illegal?

Comment: Whether such tools are illegal depends on how you define them.

I suggest you mean non-Microsoft tools, or the Question would not arise. Correct me as you will…

Can you say how a non-MS activation tool for any MS product could be legal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the tool circumvents Windows' copy protection (which is a computer question, not a legal one, but I cannot imagine a circumstance in which this isn't access-circumvention), then it is a violation of [17 USC 1201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1201), which forbids "circumvent[ing] a technological measure that effectively controls access to a work protected under this title". It is both illegal to use, and to "manufacture, import, offer to the public, provide, or otherwise traffic" in such a program.

Comment: Windows doesn't have copy protection. You can create as many copies of the installation media as you like. And Windows Activation these days doesn't even control access - I've been using a non-activated installation of Windows 10 for years and there's very little difference. More info: https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-used-without-activation/

Comment: @AaronF it does limit what you can do though, such as restricting some settings (darkmode, personalizations, themes, desktop background, etc). None of that is needed, but using a tool to unlock those functionalities definitely seems like circumventing access control. There's also has a watermark on unactivated windows, and I would assume that removing that might also fall under that code.

Comment: @tim yes that's all true. Though, now I'm wondering...if Github - a Microsoft-owned company - host and grant public access to scripts ([Microsoft-Activation-Scripts](https://github.com/massgravel/Microsoft-Activation-Scripts)) which activate Windows and Office products; then could that be seen as Microsoft approving of such scripts?

Comment: @AaronF I doubt that Microsoft acts as a publisher on github (with all the associated responsibilities). So any code posted by 3rd parties which may infringe on copyrights (or which is otherwise legally questionable), is likely the responsibility of the uploader, not of Microsoft.  ianal, but I don't think we can infer anything from those sorts of scripts being hosted on github.

Comment: @tim: You are probably right, but note that this is governed by the DMCA, and *not* by section 230 (the latter has an explicit carve-out for intellectual property). GitHub has good faith safe harbor protections, but not the full blown "not considered the publisher" immunity that you get from section 230, and that might make a difference in some legal contexts.

Answer (score 4):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

The Computer Misuse Act 1990 prohibits this:

> **1 Unauthorised access to computer material.**
>
> (1) A person is guilty of an offence if—
> (a) he causes a computer to perform any function with intent to secure access to any program or data held in any computer, or to enable any such access to be secured;
> (b) the access he intends to secure, or to enable to be secured, is unauthorised; and
> (c) he knows at the time when he causes the computer to perform the function that that is the case.

Section 3A of the Act, which was introduced in 2006, makes it an offence to make, adapt, supply or offer to supply any article intending it to be used, or believing it will be used, to commit, or to assist in the commission of, an offence under section 1.

Section 4 provides that there has only to be "one significant link" with a UK jurisdiction for the offences to be committed. So it may be that the person is in the UK but the program or the supplied article is not; or the person is outside the UK but the offence happens in the UK.

Comment: Do these programs allow you to "secure access to any program or data held in any computer..." that "... is unauthorised" when Windows freely grants access to the Windows program without them? It just restricts certain functions of that program.

Comment: Yes, because the programs unlock those functions.

Answer (score -3):

Is it illegal? Of course. It's tantamount to software piracy.

Is anyone going to stop you? No.

Even if you walked up to your local police officer and showed him what you are doing, and explained the criminality of the whole operation, his most likely response is to shrug and tell you to quit bothering him with nonsense.

Now, if you're doing this as part of some money-making criminal enterprise (something significantly more than just working out of your home), you would have trouble (although for many more reasons than just pirating Windows!)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).